# running multiple api calls (dependent on one's output) in parallel to speed up output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, api, python-requests

I am trying to run a series of Wikipedia API calls and the output of some of the calls are used in another function(for another API call). the individual API calls are fast(>1 minute) but the function that utilizes these API calls together takes approx. 1 hour.

first API call:

```
def img(cat_title) -> list:
    
    url="https://co.media.org/w/api.php"
    params = {
                "action": "query",
                "format": "json",
        }
    resp = requests.get(url, params)
    response = resp.json()
    files_list = [response['query']['pages'][str(pageid)]['title'] for pageid in list(response['query']['pages'].keys())]
    while response: #continuation for response length greater than 500
        try: 
            params.update(response['continue'])
            resp = requests.get(url, params)
            response = resp.json()
            files_list += [response['query']['pages'][str(pageid)]['title'] for pageid in list(response['query']['pages'].keys())]
        except:
            break

    return files_list

img('Category:...')
```

second API call:

```
def user(title) -> str:
    
    
    url="https://co.media.org/w/api.php"

    params = {
            "action": "gpquery",
            "format": "json",
    }

    resp = requests.get(url, params)
    response = resp.json()
    
    response_pages = response['query']['pages'] 
    page_id = list(response_pages.keys())[0]  # automates the pageid for each file/a file 
    userinfo = response_pages[page_id]['imageinfo'][0]['user'] # retrieves the value of item imageinfo
    return userinfo
    
user("File:..)
```

count function: this uses a list comprehension for the above functions. the output is an integer.

```
def count(name) -> int:
   

    files_list = ['Category:.', 'Category:...', 'Category:...', 'Category:...', 'Category:...', 'Category:...', 'Category:..']
    


    for cat_name in files_list:

        users = [user(files) for files in img(cat_name) if name in user(files)]
        print(len(users))

count('cute')
```

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do, please? And what's the question? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am trying to use the response in the first API call(img(cat_title)) and the second API call(user(title)) in the third function. however, the count(name) is slow - approx 5/9 minutes but the first and second functions run in seconds individually.